# Is it valid to pass a plain function to a redux-saga effect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Is it 100% valid to pass a plain function to a "redux-saga/effects" effect?

```
function respondToAnAction() {
  console.log("hello world");. 
}

export function* sagaWatcher() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(actionsTypes.anAction, respondToAnAction),
  ]);
}
```

Or are there caveats to doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course!

It's done all the time with `call` as in

```
yield call(plainFunction)
```

Under the hood, the only difference between `takeEvery` and `call` is that `call` is a one time effect, while `takeEvery` will respond each time an action goes through the middleware, and then call that function with `call`.